# Android: Drawing a line using a bitmap

Tags: android

Is there a way to draw a line on a Canvas where the line itself is a bitmap (as opposed to a solid color)?  I can't find any way of doing this despite a lot of searching.

Note: I'm not talking about drawing a line INTO a bitmap, as is commonly asked.  Also I'm not talking about filling a shape with a bitmap as you might do with Paint.setShader(BitmapShader).  Same concept, but I want the stroke to be rendered with the bitmap, not the fill.

Comment: I am quite sure _Canvas.drawBitmapMesh_ can be used to draw line too. If you supply it with _meshWidth=meshHeight=1_ and _verts_ contains line start and end positions for _quad_ I believe it draws a line using given Bitmap. Not sure is this what you are after though since I have no idea what _outer line_ refers to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I changed "outer line" to be "stroke" for clarity.